# Doubt on signature verification

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Hello i am making a project on state channel logic. My idea is to make a consultancy service and i am using socket.io as chat element. I know that i need to sign a message and verify it on offchain and onchain. But problem is all messages which both user gonna have will be in socket.io, How can i make a signature of those message? And is there any need to sign messages of the real time chat??
I have a close channel function in solidity script which takes signature and message as arguments, if i don't sign any message i will not get signature so would not able to verify the user.
This is how i emiting and listening for message by socket.io:

```
function handleSendMessage() {
        const messages = {
            message: newMessage,
            roomId: room,
            user: currentUser,
        }

        setMessage([..._message, messages.message])
        socket.emit("messages_from_client", messages)
    }

useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("messages_from_server", (messages) => {
```

All i need to know is how can i sign a message here so that i can call `closeChannel()`??